# Best way to store menu list in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, cookies, user-roles

You have an Asp.Net Mc project and you use master layout structure, IoC, repository pattern etc. You should generate menu according to users role permissons. For example if the user is not admin, user should not see the menu item in your menu. And here is the question, what is the best way to fill left menu ? By stored cookie, stored in cache, connect to db every user login, session or another way ? What is the best way ?

Comment: It largely depends: if you have a million users, storing in cache may not be ideal. If you store in cookie, how do you decide when the cookie should expire; imaging the user had a role but no longer does etc. I would just connect to db every time and see if that is good enough for my performance needs and leave it at that and move on. If not, explore other options.

Comment: i dont have many users but it's a SaaS application. Yes maybe cookie is not ideal, what about Session["menulist"]  ?

Comment: Cookies and Session are similar but one travels to client (cookie) and the other stays on the server. If the user's roles cannot change within a session period, it should be fine.

Comment: Is the relationship of roles to menu options supposed to be configurable at runtime? If not just write a method that hardcodes the role-menu mapping and call it a day. It can be tempting to lean on the database for unlimited configurability, but unless you actually need something to change at runtime, putting it in source code is more performant, more traceable, and not much harder to update if you have a good CI process